# Benchpress Samples result generation

Tags: angularjs, performance-testing

I am trying to run one test using [Angular Benchpress](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-benchpress) framework. I followed the steps as mentioned in the above link. But when I navigate to http://localhost:3339/benchpress-build, I do not see any sample report.

Where the benchpress generates the performance test report?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: I followed the steps which are mentioned in https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-benchpress. I am not sure where to see the performance metrics.